# PDF file that generated by itext is corrupted if the PDF file is generated by a jar extension application

Tags: java, pdf, jar, itext

I'm newbie in Java and I desperately need your help.

Currently I'm working on my project which requires me to generate PDF file from certain user inputs. My output PDF file is expected to contain images in several cells. Everything seems okay if I run the application in Netbeans IDE. I try to open the generated PDF file and it's nice. No problem at all.

Then I do the 'Clean and Build' thing so I'll have an application with jar extension. This where the problem is. If I generate the PDF file from this jar-extension-application, the PDF file is corrupted. It says that  'An error occured'. I see the size of the file is (always) 0 bytes. But if I remove the codes for 'adding-images-in-cells' in my source code, the PDF file is not corrupted. It can be opened, but the consequence is my file doesn't contain any image.

My questions are:

- Am I possibly doing something wrong in the code so that the error occurs? Or is it natural that I can not generated PDF file using the 'jar-extension-application' if that file contains any image?
- How come the file is generated nicely if run directly in Netbeans IDE, but get the opposite after if run in jar extension?

Thanks for any answer.

Comment: Are the relative paths of images valid when accessed through the jar?

Comment: Please post the errors that you are getting.  Unless the exceptions are getting swallowed up by your code, I am sure they have some interesting tails to tell.

Comment: PopFibo is right. In Netbeans, you are working on your local system, using local paths to find the images. Wherever you use the jar, the working directory, the access permissions, the paths,... are different. Most probably, an exception is thrown (and ignored or "eaten") when an image isn't found, resulting in a PDF files that is never written (0 bytes). This problem isn't related to iText.

Comment: Finally, the problem is solved. The problem isn't related to iText at all.

**I should check whether the relative paths of images are valid or not** because Netbeans is working in local system so the paths are totally different whenever I use the jar. So, I use the getResource function to get the relative path of my images. That's all.

Thanks for your response. I really appreciate it.. :)